# Fancybox form ajax post close on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in a div. The table contains a link to add a row. Clicking on the link opens a fancybox2 with the form to add the new row. 
I am facing the following issues: the lightbox close and the entire page reload.

**UPDATED: through more debugging seems that the form is posted to the page but in Firebug I see that the target page is marked in red, receive the posted values but returns nothing.**
I open the fancybox with:

```
$('.new').fancybox({
        type: 'ajax',
        autoSize : true,
        padding: 5,
        closeClick: false,
        autoResize:true
    });
```

the form page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_submit(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bp/new_row1.php",
            data: $('#new_row').serialize(),
            success: function(data){$.fancybox(data);}
        })
    }
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#insert').click(function(){ajax_submit();});
});
</script>
<form name="new_row" id="new_row">
    <div class="sez-form"><label>Descrizione: </label><input tabindex="10" name="descr" id="descr" size="100" maxlength="256"></div>
    <div class="sez-form"><label>Tempestivo ammesso: </label><input tabindex="10" name="descr" id="descr" size="65" maxlength="65"></div>
    <div class="sez-form"><label>Tardivo ammesso: </label><input tabindex="10" name="descr" id="descr" size="65" maxlength="65"></div>
    <div class="sez-form"><button id="insert"><?php echo $azione; ?></button><button id="undo">Annulla</button></div>
</form>
```

The destination page for the posted values is just:

```
<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>
```

Thank eveyone who will help me!

Comment: Try `parent.window.close();` in success function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either one should work, inside the success function.

`parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();` Or `parent.window.close();`

Comment: the point is exactly the opposite. The lightbox close and reload the whole page without posting.